# C# Class Library or Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application that talks to an AS400 backend system.
I made calls to AS400 Programs through IBM iSeries Client Access Library

Which way is correct

a) Create a class library with all functionalities and reference through my Web Application or

b) Create a Web API, make a reference to the class library and host it to IIS

I think this is a better solution because it would be in another application in IIS and not in the same process as in the first approach. I will be more asynchronous. I'm right?

Comment: I don't think there's a correct answer for this as they're both fine solutions. Need to look at the pros and cons for both and make a decision. What are your requirements, like it needs to be very fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used both a and b in same system(as400 and .net), but for different cases. If you want to isolate as400 things from your application, then go with web api(b). This will give you more flexibility to work(maintain wise). And this way good if you have many functions with deal with. This will also make your life complex. Like security...

I used case a, when I just need to do only a login through as400 and few more things.

Usability with other applications

a) You can reference that dll to many other applications(.net only)

b) You can use api for almost any type of application

Comment: Is it correct if I go with the solution b that it will be more asynchronous? Because it is in new application in IIS and the client can use it through async http API instead of class library that it will be in the same process as my web application

Comment: if your only concern is async, then you can achieve that using a also. and one more thing, does iseries supports asynchronous calls(not sure)???

Comment: No it doesn't support. But I think through Web API in another IIS application host and async c# http client can archive that

Comment: If it is not supporting, i don't think you can achieve async. It will give warning like, "this method lack of async calls".